# Check for url slash count pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write an regualr expression to match invalid url patterns

I want to match following pattern :

```
/article/test-string/
```

Above is invalid url, but following are valid

```
/article/abc/test-string/ and /article/xyz/abc/test-string/
```

I want to match those which have only one value after article slash. 
Please help, I am trying using following, but it is matching all :

```
/article/(.*)/$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` matches 0 or more of any character so `/article/(.*)/$` will match all the URIs that have `/article/` in it.

You can use this regex to validate only only one non-slash component after `/article/`:

```
$re = '~^/article/[^/]*/$~';
```

- `[^/]*`   # matches 0 or more of any character that is not `/`
- `/$`      # matches `/` in the end
- `~`       is used as regex delimiter to avoid escaping `/`

Answer (score 1):

```
~^/article/(.*)+/(.*)/$~gm
^ assert position at start of a line
/article/ matches the characters /article/ literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing group (.*)+
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
/ matches the character / literally
2nd Capturing group (.*)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
/ matches the character / literally
$ assert position at end of a line
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

```
$re = "~^/article/(.*)+/(.*)/$~m"; 
$str = "/article/xyz/abc/test-string/\n/article/test-string/"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

> source https://regex101.com/

Comment: thanks Abhijit, this explanation is really very useful.`'~^/article/[^/]*/$~';` solved my purpose